# Auto hide navigation on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have this code, and I'm trying to understand how it works.

Let's say, I wanna make it auto hide when click on link on mobile, what should I add to my code? I guess it is something with js

Begginer here, so thanks to everyone! :)

```js
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  // Mobile Navigation
  if ($('.main-nav').length) {
    var $mobile_nav = $('.main-nav').clone().prop({
      class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
    });
    $('body').append($mobile_nav);
    $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>');
    $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
      $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
      $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav .drop-down > a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
  } else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
    $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header" class="fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

  <div class="logo float-left">
      <a href="#intro" class="scrollto"><img src="assets/img/logo/logo2.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
  </div>

  <nav class="main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block">
      <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#welcome">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#our-services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#why-choose-us">Why Choose Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav><!-- .main-nav -->

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: it would be a good idea if you use css instead of jQuery, using media queries if the width is less then a certain point  (375px standard for mobile now days), you set the particular part to display as none you can read more about the media queries here at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp or if you wanna do with JavaScript you can use JavaScript use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to get the height and width of the device and set the perticular part to display none.

Comment: Can you place your CSS in here too? So it's easier to help you

Comment: @DiogoPeres, sure, I did